# PHP and MySQLi query always returning 0

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

The following code seems to be not working correctly. I'm new to PHP and jQuery.

php:

```
<?php

//if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

//if we got something through $_POST
if (isset($_POST['postcode_locator_search'])) {
    // here you would normally include some database connection
    //include('config.local.php');

    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','test','c@W)ukmd[0bm','test');

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    // never trust what user wrote! We must ALWAYS sanitize user input
    $postcode_q = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postcode_locator_search']);
    $postcode_q = htmlentities($postcode_q);

    // A select query. $result will be a `mysqli_result` object if successful
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT description FROM cscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE cscart_postcode_location_descriptions LIKE '%" . $postcode_q . "%' ORDER BY cscart_postcode_location_descriptions LIMIT 1");

    if($result === false) {
        // Handle failure - log the error, notify administrator, etc.
        echo '1';
    } else {
        // Fetch all the rows in an array
        echo '0';
    }

    $mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

JS / HTML:

```
{assign var="prod_id" value=$product.product_id}

<form action="search_postcode.php" method="post" class="postcode_locator_form" name="postcode_locator_form">
    <div class="ty-control-group">
        <label for="postcode_locator_search{$block.block_id}" class="ty-control-group__title">{__("postcode_search")}</label>
        <p class="filling-notice">{__("postcode_search_desc")}</p>
        <div class="ty-input-append ty-m-none">
            <input type="text" size="20" class="ty-input-text" id="postcode_locator_search" name="postcode_locator_search" value="{$postcode_locator_search.q}" />
            {include file="buttons/go.tpl" but_name="postcode_locator.search" alt=__("search")}
        </div>

    </div>
</form>

<div class="filling-status filling-success">
    <h3>Add filling to your bean bag</h3>
    <p>Searched postcode: <span class="searched-postcode"></span></p>
    <p class="beans-msg">{__("add_some_beans_success")} <a href="{"checkout.add_bean_bag_filling&product_id=`$product.product_id`"|fn_url}">{__("click_here")}</a></p>
</div>
<div class="filling-status filling-failure">
    <h3>Add filling to your bean bag</h3>
    <p>Searched postcode: <span class="searched-postcode"></span></p>
    <p class="beans-msg">{__("add_some_beans_error")}</p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

    $(".filling-status").hide();
    $(".postcode_locator_form .ty-btn-go").click(function() {
        // getting the value that user typed
        var searchString    = $("#postcode_locator_search").val();
        // forming the queryString
        var data            = 'postcode_locator_search='+ searchString;

        // if searchString is not empty
        if(searchString) {
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_postcode.php",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function(html) { // this happens before actual call
                    $(".searched-postcode").html(searchString);
                },
                success: function(data){ // this happens after we get results
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == '0'){
                        $(".filling-status.filling-success").show();
                    } else  if(data == '1'){
                        $(".filling-status.filling-failure").show();
                    }
                }
            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The communication is all working, but it always returns 0 as a success from whatever I search for and seems to not check database for the result.

What I need is if I search something and it's a match, to return 0 as a success but if not found / a match to return 1 as a failure.

Comment: Because it says in your condition. It fetches all your data's and echoed string 0;

Comment: How can i fix it? sorry im new to PHP so trial and error up until now and almost 2am haha

Comment: Have you logged the error you are receiving when running the query? Seems like you have invalid table/field names in your query. Are both your table and your field name really `cscart_postcode_location_descriptions`?

Comment: Im not getting an error, its just always turning as 0 (true) which is not the case so something wrong with my code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve your data:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT description FROMcscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE cscart_postcode_location_descriptions LIKE '%" . $postcode_q . "%' ORDER BY cscart_postcode_location_descriptions LIMIT 1");

if($result === false) {
    // Handle failure - log the error, notify administrator, etc.
    echo '1';
} else {
    // Fetch all the rows in an array
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['id']; //prints the resulted id
    }
}
```

Comment: And please refer to @DGS answer too.

Comment: I tried both solutions but always returns 0, even something random that is not in result... :( maybe my query is wrong in some way?

Comment: may be this is the problem in your code `$postcode_q = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postcode_locator_search']);
    $postcode_q = htmlentities($postcode_q);`

Comment: there is no error, console.log(data) always returns 0 whatever i put in the search

Comment: Can you `print_r($results);` ? outside the if and else statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87326/discussion-between-james-and-aldrin27).

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_num_rows` to detect if you have a result

```
if($result === false or mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {
    echo '1';
}
```

I would recommend breaking this into two if conditions though so that you handle errors separately from a query with no result

Comment: I tried that but same as other answer, i type something that is not a valid result and something that should be and both return valid?

Comment: What is not valid? echo out your query when you are expecting it to fail and see what it is actually querying

Comment: echo your query `echo "SELECT description FROM cscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE cscart_postcode_location_descriptions LIKE '%" . $postcode_q . "%' ORDER BY cscart_postcode_location_descriptions LIMIT 1"`

Comment: I think the query is wrong, i was getting error i need to search the column description within the table cscart_postcode_location_descriptions

Comment: if i do SELECT description FROM cscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE description LIKE '6060' LIMIT 1; returns result if i do like 'dddddddd' does not... so that work slike that... what would i need to change?

Comment: i done "SELECT description FROM cscart_postcode_location_descriptions WHERE description LIKE ".$postcode_q." LIMIT 1" but returns true all the time